# Swift error: "MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The error message screenshot:
[image]

When I click the "click here" button in the paragraph that says "If you forgot your username/password, **click here** to send a verification message that contains your username/password to your email address", the dialogue box pops up and says "MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly", and that message is the error I want to solve.

This class below this sentence is the Swift code for the page that has the "click here" button which generates the error I want to solve. It is the ViewController class.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var ClickHereSendEmailButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SignInButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedSignInButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        if UsernameTextField.text == username && PasswordTextField.text == password
        {
            // create the alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Correct", message: "Your credentials are correct.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            // add an action (button)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            // show the alert
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            Label.text = "The credentials are correct."
            UsernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            PasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        else
        {
            // create the alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Incorrect", message: "Your credentials are incorrect.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            // add an action (button)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            // show the alert
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            Label.text = "The credentials are not correct."
            UsernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            PasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func PressedClickHereSendEmailButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is the AppDelegate class

```
import UIKit


@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }
}
```

Create account page:

```
import UIKit

var username = ""
var password = ""
var email = ""

class CreateAccountPage: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var UserNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ActivateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ReturnButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedActivateButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
      username = UserNameTextField.text!
      password = PasswordTextField.text!
      email = EmailAddressTextField.text!

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Activated", message: "Your new account is now activated.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func ReturnButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
    }

    //performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil
}
```

EDIT: I also included two screenshots so please view them to make it clear.
EDIT #2: I would post more screenshots of the storyboard links but I can only post two, so let me know and I'll email them.

Comment: Do you have a mail account configured on your simulator? You should check `canSendMail` before trying to create the compose view controller

Comment: I don't have an email account configured on my simulator. What do you mean by "check canSendMail"... Oh like are you saying in the if statement that says "MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() might be nil or something? I am confused.

Comment: Yes, you create the mail compose view controller and hen you check whether you can send mail. Check first whether you can send and if you can then you can create the compose view controller. But, as others have answered you can't send mail from the simulator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly` error is a simulator bug. Run your mail sending code on a real device to test it.

Comment: No problem. You accepted an answer which someone copied from my answer.

Comment: The thing is that I was first that answered correctly. Then someone else copied my answer and submitted it after me. No big deal, but in general you should accept first correct answer and not the one that was copied.

Comment: Okay I clicked yours now, did that do anything?

Answer (score 1):

This is simulator problem not your problem , Try to connect your iPhone using usb and select it from Xcode then run the application , it should work without error , if there is an errors let us know